# phantomjs tests with mysql database

Tags: mysql, phantomjs

I programmed a test szenario in phantomjs. Standalone its working.

Now I'd like to run the same tests on several websites. The list of urls is comming from mysql and the results should be written back into the database. Just wondering:

Is it possible to directly connect to a database from within phantomjs?

What would be the best approach to do this?

Comment: Do you have to use mysql but not other database such as sqlite?

Comment: Yes, its part of a bigger application running on php and mysql

Comment: Then why not store the data to file and use php to read the data the deal with them?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to expose the mysql database as an HTTP API. Then you can connect from your phantom.js script and run queries.

Here is a similar issue: https://major.io/2012/03/28/mysql-json-bridge-a-simple-json-api-for-mysql/
and
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/HPpheJ45Xs4

And a PHP-based Rest API for mysql: http://phprestsql.sourceforge.net/